# Mass of function concentrating near origin

Tags: integration, limits

Let $$g_t(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\frac{-(at+x)^2}{4t}}$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$. Fix $r>0$. Why is it true that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{|y|>r}g_t(y)dy=0?$$
We can show that $\int_\mathbb{R}g_t(y)dy=2\sqrt{\pi}$ for any $t>0$. Basically, this result says that as $t\rightarrow 0^+$, the mass of the function is concentrated near $0$.